# Convert mongoDB Aggregation Query to Spring data mongo template Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am fairly new to MongoDb and Spring-data-Mongo.
After doing a lot of research I was able to get the desired result in MongoDB using the below query, but now I am finding it very difficult to implement the same logic in the Spring-data-Mongo template.

The logic is pretty simple:

I have 2 date fields and 2 integer fields in the document.

`expireLastModifiedD` (Integer Represents Days), `expireLastUsedD`: (Integer, Represents days), `lastModified`: (Date type), `lastUsed`: (Date Type).

I need to find Documents that satisfy the below expression.

```
lastModified+expireLastModifiedD < NOW && lastUsed + expireLastUsedD < NOW
```

I have created a MongoDB Query as under.

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      expireLastModifiedD: 1,
      expireLastUsedD: 1,
      lastModified: 1,
      lastUsed: 1,
      NowSubtractLastModified: {
        $toInt: {
          $divide: [
            {
              $subtract: [
                new ISODate(),
                "$lastModified"
              ]
            },
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          ]
        }
      },
      NowSubtractLastused: {
        $toInt: {
          $divide: [
            {
              $subtract: [
                new ISODate(),
                "$lastUsed"
              ]
            },
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      expireLastModifiedD: 1,
      expireLastUsedD: 1,
      lastModified: 1,
      lastUsed: 1,
      NowSubtractLastModified: 1,
      NowSubtractLastused: 1,
      isExpireLastModifiedDLTNowSubtractLastModified: {
        $lt: [
          "$expireLastModifiedD",
          "$NowSubtractLastModified"
        ]
      },
      isExpireLastUsedDLTNowSubtractLastused: {
        $lt: [
          "$expireLastUsedD",
          "$NowSubtractLastused"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      isExpireLastModifiedDLTNowSubtractLastModified: true,
      isExpireLastUsedDLTNowSubtractLastused: true
    }
  }
]
```

I need help creating the above MongoDb query in Spring-data Mongo Template using Aggregation.

Comment: take a look at ```org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation``` package. it has all operators that you need for the above query. Also, check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.supported-aggregation-operations

Answer (score 0):

After Lot of Research, I figured it out.

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Timestamp current = Timestamp.from(now);

    ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("lastUsed", "expireLastUsedD", "lastModified", "expireLastModifiedD")
            .andExpression("([0] - lastModified)", current).divide(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).as("lastModifiedFromNowD")
            .andExpression("([0] - lastUsed)", current).divide(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).as("lastUsedFromNowD");

    ProjectionOperation projectionOperation1 = Aggregation.project("lastUsed", "expireLastUsedD", "lastModified", "expireLastModifiedD", "lastModifiedFromNowD", "lastUsedFromNowD")
            .andExpression("expireLastModifiedD < lastModifiedFromNowD").as("isExpLstModLTLastModFromNowD")
            .andExpression("expireLastUsedD < lastUsedFromNowD").as("isExpLstUsdLtLstUsdFromNowD");

    MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(
            Criteria.where("isExpLstModLTLastModFromNowD").is(true), Criteria.where("isExpLstUsdLtLstUsdFromNowD").is(true)));

    TypedAggregation<UrlMap> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(UrlMap.class,
            projectionOperation, projectionOperation1, matchOperation);
```